# Uninitialized Local Variable in Switch Statement - Win32 API

Tags: c++, api, winapi, switch-statement

Alright here is my code I will just provide one function sense the rest of it would not be any helpful. I have been searching for the problem and can not seem to figure it out.

> Error: uninitialized local variable 'hTextBox' used   Win32Project2

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    RECT rect;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HWND hTextBox;

    switch (message)
    {

        case WM_CREATE:
            hTextBox = CreateWindow(L"edit", L"", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER, 5, 5, 200, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            CreateWindow(L"button", L"Click me!", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 20, 40, 75, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:

            switch (LOWORD(wparam))
            {
            case 1:
                int returnedCharacters = 0;
                returnedCharacters = GetWindowText(hTextBox, &szTextSaved[0], 20);
                break;
            }


        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            DrawText(hdc, L"This is a text message!", -1, &rect,  DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not static, so it won't remember what happened in WM_CREATE

Comment: Thanks :D, The guy never mentioned that, so I didn't know.